# does the flag review consider the state when flagging?

Tags: support, flags

My question is, if I flag some answer as **it is not an answer** than the user edited his answer before the my flag is reviewed, and put an actual answer, as there is no way cancelling the flag, what would actually happen?

Would the reviewer check the state when the flag is made, or the latest state?

Answer (score 4):

The not an answer flag enters the 10k review queue, where it is then reviewed by 10k users who can either raise an invalid flag, or choose to raise another flag.

After just checking, it seems as though the reviewer is presented with the **updated** state; rather than the initial state seen upon flagging. Thus, if an edit is made, your flag *may* not reflect the state presented to the reviewer, as they are seeing the updated/edited state.

I went through over 70+ not an answer flags in order to find one that had been updated since the time it was originally flagged, therefore it doesn't seem to be a very common occurrence.

**Here is [one of the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19894911/revisions) I found:**

This answer was flagged at `2013-11-26 14:56:04Z`, and later updated at `2013-11-26 17:45:18Z`.

The updated state of the answer is presented to the reviewer.

> [image]
>
> [image]